# How can I create a domain name with a custom extension, like .example instead of .com?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains, website-features, personal-website

Is it possible to get my own website with a special ending prefix? Instead of `.com` I want to have my initials instead or something like that. Is that plausible by any chance?

I went to websites like GoDaddy which don't sell domain with the ending I would want, and I honestly have no idea what to search on google.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you can not.

In 2012 ICANN selected new TLDs after a long procedure. Applicants needed to pay $185,000 just to give their application, without any guarantees. And this is a very small part of both setup and ongoing costs that happen for successful applications.

Note that applicants needed to be moral entities, not individuals (one might argue there is an exception for a guy that named one of its company with its lastname and hence applying for both its lastname/company name).

The whole https://newgtlds.icann.org/ website should give you pointers about all the above, but look specifically at https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/about/program for an overview.

It is expected that applications will start to be accepted again in the future, but

1. no one knows when (speculations are wild but nothing has been announced by ICANN and with GDPR taking a large amount of resources, one might expect some more delays, which is something that plagues almost all ICANN endeavours)
2. no one knows the specifics, the costs, etc. basically how much similar it will be to previous round or not (specifically if it will be the same cost as many argues it was too high and in fact a large portion of it was just provisions over future litigations and most part of it was not spent at all)
3. and specifically, I doubt that individuals will be allowed anyway.

So whatever you are trying to achieve, you sure need to find another way right now.

My belief is that any good idea could thrive whatever the name is used...

Comment: Thanks! this was very helpful info, I was wondering if such a thing was within the realm of possibility for just an average Joe. I guess I should have known it was bigger than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but extremely expensive.   Expect to pay at least one hundred thousand US dollars.   A few companies have obtained their own custom top level domains.   There is .google for example.  The up front costs and technical requirements put custom top level domains out of the reach of most web sites and companies.

If you want to learn more search for "top level domain expansion."

Comment: thanks for the helpful info!! I'll definitely check the search out!